# Temporary permissions problem in grep in one window

Tags: grep, gnome-terminator

**Trying to understand my issue here**. I have a window which somehow has LOST permissions to grep. I honestly have no clue how. I'd like to know, understand, have at least an inkling what might've happened. Ideas?

1. Terminator screen A, dirA, can grep without a problem.
2. Same Terminator window, screen B, dirB, cannot grep (outputs: `grep number: permission denied`). Both dirs have SAME permissions.
3. I cd from dirB to dirA. I cannot grep. Again, output says `grep number: permission denied`, just number increases by 1.
4. Both windows are opened from Terminator (same one). New Terminator window has no problems. New Terminator or terminal - no problem.
5. I didn't change permissions.
6. I didn't add/remove/change groups or users.
7. The - now faulty - window originally COULD grep.
8. Running `zsh` in a faulty window "enables" grep back, until I quit the shell.

I think if I close this window and reopen a new one I'll fix it, but I'm curious - WHAT caused it?

### Running:

1. Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
2. ZSH (version says `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`) with Oh-My-ZSH
3. Terminator 0.98 (though I don't suspect Terminator, it's just one screen in one window that hs this peculiar issue and it is first time I've had it).
4. Inxi report below

   inxi -S -xxx
   System:    Host: T420s Kernel: 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
              Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.28) info: xfce4-panel dm: lightdm
              Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial

### Grep commands causing the problem:

and the error message.

```
➜  dirA ±:(master) grep pom client/pom.xml                         [% 20:35:05]
grep:66: permission denied: client/src/main/java/client/BatClient.java
➜  dirA ±:(master) grep a pom.xml                                  [% 20:35:20]
grep:67: permission denied: client/src/main/java/client/BatClient.java
➜  dirA ±:(master) grep a client/pom.xml                           [% 20:38:53]
grep:68: permission denied: client/src/main/java/client/BatClient.java
```

In dirB a file that has denied permission changes.

### I killed the window as I had to restart the server.

Killing the window made the glitch go away.
Next time this appears, I'll reopen the question and add syscall debug or dig output perhaps.

Great many thanks to you for helping!

Comment: I'm not sure what caused the downvote. I'd like to make the question better but I'd need some help here.

Comment: Maybe a terminator glitch!

Comment: Please copy the **exact** `grep` command that you are executing and the complete **verbatim** error message and paste them into your question using the [edit] button

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen how to check?

Comment: @steeldriver done. Though formatting is making this hard. Will correct in an iffy.

Comment: 1) `type grep`; 2) it sounds a lot like just closing the tab solves your problem.

Comment: @MichaelHomer it's an alias for grep  --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn}. Yes, it does, I'm quite sure. I'm not after solution. I want to understand what actually happened.

Comment: wild guess: try running `id` in that window.  maybe you had previously run `su` or `sudo -i` or similar to change to another user id, or  (or even ssh in as another user) in that tty and forgot about it.   not being the uid you thought you were is one of the few legitimate reasons for something like this to happen.

Comment: Also, where are the 66, 67,68 numbers coming from in your example error messages?  that's not the standard grep error message - normally `grep: filename: Permission denied`.  Is that being done by zsh or oh-my-zsh somehow?

Comment: @cas - thanks - tried both `id` and `whoami` and got my normal user, no elevated privileges or different acount.

Comment: @cas I've tried grepping a file where I clearly had no permissions and got a different (than mine) message, so I don't think this was ZSH/OMZ.

Answer (score 2):

```
➜  dirA ±:(master) grep pom client/pom.xml                         [% 20:35:05]
grep:66: permission denied: client/src/main/java/client/BatClient.java
```

Should there be a battery percentage value of some sort next to the time value, where there's currently just a percent sign?

If so, the "permission denied" error and the missing percentage value might be related to each other: whatever your Oh-My-ZSH is doing to get that percentage could be failing, and could be causing the `grep` command execution to fail (i.e. the actual command might not get executed at all) as a side effect.

Note that the message is not just "permission denied", but `permission denied: client/src/main/java/client/BatClient.java`. BatClient sounds like something that might be used to read a battery charge value.

Comment: Your thinking is admirable, but I don't think that's the case here. I checked my prompt. RPROMPT='[%# %*]', that is escalation and datetime with seconds in 24h format. BatClient is totally irrelevant to battery as well. Finally, in dirB, it's Chain...java. My guess is it's first (alphabetically) file that grep reaches in a given directory.